Tabularray multicolumn table with long text goes over the margin
I have the following code that uses tblr which has a paragraph go over the margin, which isn't the intended result.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
  width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
  hlines, vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
}
  Junior High Janitor & & January 2022 - May 2024 \\
  \SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[1] \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

I want it to be left aligned, but not putting {l} produces another error. I hope it's clear what I want to happen with this table. Would appreciate any help given

You need to use hspan=minimal
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
            width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
            hlines, vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
            hspan=minimal,
        }
        Junior High Janitor & & January 2022 - May 2024 \\
        \SetCell[c=3]{l} \lipsum[1] & & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}


Explanation:
From the tabularray documentation:

With hspan=default or hspan=even, tabularray package will compute
column widths from span widths. But with hspan=minimal, it will
compute span widths from column widths.

In this case, you want to use your column widths instead of the spancell width
EDIT: If you want full justify text, you can use j instead:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {X X X[r]}, % specify column widths
            width = \linewidth, % table width is the linewidth
            hlines, vlines, % horizontal and vertical lines
            hspan=minimal,
        }
        Junior High Janitor & & January 2022 - May 2024 \\
        \SetCell[c=3]{j} \lipsum[1] & & \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}



But how come the text isn't affected by microtype? this is something that I want to have an effect as I loaded it in with my list of packages.

You are not asking for that in your original question. Furthermore what do you exactly mean with microtype in effect?

I tried loading and not loading microtype and it does effect the text. Perhaps you want a full justification, so I edited my answer to add that
